# How to call bean method after Lazy Datatable is fully loaded?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi may I know how do I call a method in the backing bean after the data table is loaded ? `<p:ajax event="load"/>` is not supported. I plan to use remoteCommand to call the method inside the bean but I am not sure how as I cannot find any ajax events or dataTable attributes to call the remote after it is fully loaded.

Help is much apreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You could try adding a `<p:remoteCommand name="doIt" action="#{myBean.doSomethingUseful()}" autoRun="true"/>` that AJAX-invokes your method on first view impression. If you want to invoke your method on subsequent (re)loading events, you can add AJAX handlers for a number of additional events like `page`, `filter` etc.

Comment: @selaron: sounds like an answer ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje you are right, added it as an answer. Too bad there is no `flag` indicating "Not a comment, should be an answer" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<p:remoteCommand name="doIt" action="#{myBean.doSomethingUseful()}" autoRun="true"/>` that AJAX-invokes your method on first view impression.

If you want to invoke your method on subsequent (re)loading events, you can add AJAX handlers for a number of additional events like `page`, `filter` etc. like this:

```
<p:dataTable ...>
    <p:ajax event="page" process="@this" listener="#{myBean.doSomethingUseful()}"/>
     ...
</dataTable>
```

Be sure to not update a component containing your `p:remoteCommand` using AJAX as this would invoke your method either.